# Login using /wp-admin doesn't redirect back to /wp-admin

Tags: plugin-development

A custom plugin redirects login to another page.

If the user types /wp-login.php then the browser redirects to a custom login page. In the browser URL, the redirect= is included and after proper credentials the user is sent back to the original WordPress post or page.

If the user types /wp-admin then the browser redirects to the custom login page. In the browser URL, the redirect= is included however after proper credentials the user is *not* sent back to /wp-admin.

The redirect= in the browser looks correct so I'm not understanding why there is a problem.

Here is the code.

```
function xf_login_redirect( $login_url, $redirect ) {

    $login_url = Class::Url . '/login';

    $redirect = wp_guess_url;

    if ( strpos( $login_url, '?' ) === false ) {
        return $login_url . '?redirect_to=' . $redirect;
    } else {
        return $login_url . '&redirect_to=' . $redirect;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_url', 'xf_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

I'm assuming using wp_guess_url is causing the issue, even though the browser is being redirected to the custom login page. It's the fact that after proper credentials then the browser doesn't redirect to /wp-admin.

Can someone point me to an explanation of login with /wp-admin and a better way to hook to redirect to the custom login page and have it return to /wp-admin?

Comment: Did you check example given on codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect#Examples)

Comment: The login_redirect is different from login_url, right? My question stems from the use of someone typing /wp-admin, being redirected to a custom login page, then redirecting back into /wp-admin. I'm not sure how login_redirect fits into that scenario since /wp-admin is already redirecting to login but never back to /wp-admin.